# Does express automatically responds to the exploit scan requests like the attached?

Tags: node.js, express

I am wondering, how all these random exploit scans on my website seems to generate HTTP code 200.
I don't have those routes defined in my code, just curious to understand whats happening here.
I have even tried to define my own route (e.g. phppatch/php) just to capture what junk is coming through these requests but the calls are not even reaching my route methods.

I am using express (v4.12+), and running on latest version of nodejs. No ngnix layer in front..

[image: server log]

Comment: is your "Not Fond" page incorrectly returning a 200 status code? notice how the response size is always the same.

Comment: @kevinB , Actually I don't have the 'not found' handler.. If I try to access a page/route that doesn't exist I get a proper 404. And the consistent response size is the reason for thinking there may be some initial threat handler inside nodejs or express.